# grouping based on rolling conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to group the data-frame based on a few conditions.

Data frame:

```
Start Date  End Date    value
1971-07-01  1971-07-31  0.0
1971-08-01  1971-08-31  0.25
1971-09-01  1971-09-30  -0.62
1971-10-01  1971-10-31  0.0
1971-11-01  1971-11-30  -0.63
1971-12-01  1971-12-31  -1.0
1972-01-01  1972-01-31  0.0
1972-02-01  1972-02-29  0.0
1972-03-01  1972-03-31  2.0
1972-04-01  1972-04-30  0.0
.
.
1973-07-01  1973-07-31  2.0
1973-08-01  1973-08-31  0.5
1973-09-01  1973-09-30  -2.0
1973-10-01  1973-10-31  0.0
1973-11-01  1973-11-30  0.0
1973-12-01  1973-12-31  0.0
1974-01-01  1974-01-31  0.0
1974-02-01  1974-02-28  0.0
.
.
.
1974-11-01  1974-11-30  0.0
1974-12-01  1974-12-31  -1.25
1975-01-01  1975-01-31  -1.0
1975-02-01  1975-02-28  -1.0
1975-03-01  1975-03-31  -0.5
1975-04-01  1975-04-30  -0.25
1975-05-01  1975-05-31  0.0
1975-06-01  1975-06-30  1.25
1975-07-01  1975-07-31  0.0
1975-08-01  1975-08-31  0.0
```

**Criteria for grouping**

The group should **always start with the negative value**

The group **continues as long as we have negative value**

The group **ends** if we reach either a **positive value** or **three consecutive zeros**.

Example 1 from the above data frame

```
1971-09-01  1971-09-30  -0.62
1971-10-01  1971-10-31  0.0
1971-11-01  1971-11-30  -0.63
1971-12-01  1971-12-31  -1.0
1972-01-01  1972-01-31  0.0
1972-02-01  1972-02-29  0.0
```

Example 2 (in this case we reached 3 consecutive zeros)

```
1973-09-01  1973-09-30  -2.0
1973-10-01  1973-10-31  0.0
1973-11-01  1973-11-30  0.0
1973-12-01  1973-12-31  0.0
```

Example 3 (in this case we reached a positive value)

```
1974-12-01  1974-12-31  -1.25
1975-01-01  1975-01-31  -1.0
1975-02-01  1975-02-28  -1.0
1975-03-01  1975-03-31  -0.5
1975-04-01  1975-04-30  -0.25
1975-05-01  1975-05-31  0.0
```

I have not got any code as I am still figuring out how to put the conditions into groupby or any other efficient way to do this.

I tried for loop but I am not going anywhere with that.

```py
for i in df.index:
    no = 0
    if df['Value'][i] < 0:
        df['groupno'] = no
```

After grouping, I want to get the start date of the first column of the group and the end date of the last column of the group.

Expected results (from the examples):

```
Start Date   End Date
1971-09-01   1972-02-29
1973-09-01   1973-12-31
1974-12-01   1975-05-31
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not pythonic way, but it works and I think it can be helpful for u.

```
groups = []
start = '' # start date for group
end = '' # end date for group
nulls = 0 # count of nulls
for j,i in df.iterrows():
    # if it's first negativa value - start the group
    if i.value < 0 and start == '':
        start = i['Start Date']
        nulls = 0
    # if it's null - remember that
    if i.value == 0:
        nulls += 1
    else:
        nulls = 0
    # if value > 0 or we have seen 3 nulls - end group (if it was start)
    if ( (i.value > 0) or (nulls == 3) ) and start != '':
        # if we have seen 3 nulls - we want write this end date (not previous)
        if nulls == 3:
            end = i['End Date']
        groups.append((start, end))
        start = ''
        nulls = 0
    if nulls == 3:
        start = ''
        nulls = 0
    # remember previous end date
    end = i['End Date']
result = pd.DataFrame(groups, columns = ['Start Date', 'End Date'])
print(result)
```

It isn't `group by` but it can helps find start and end date for your groups.

Out:

```
   Start Date    End Date
0  1971-09-01  1972-02-29
1  1973-09-01  1973-12-31
2  1974-12-01  1975-05-31
```

Comment: Thanks for answering